# tradingview chart time order violation error

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

I create a chart with TradingView library.this is option that i use to init chart :

```
var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
    debug: true,
    fullscreen: true,
    symbol: 'WEBT',
    interval: '60',
    height: "142px",
    container_id: "tv_chart_container",
    datafeed: new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed("/tradingview/udf"),
    library_path: "/assets/charting_library/",
    disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings"],
    charts_storage_api_version: "1.1",
    client_id: 'tradingview.dotnet',
    user_id: 'public_user_id',
    theme: getParameterByName('theme'),
    time_frames: [
        { text: "60", resolution: "60"},
        { text: "1D", resolution: "1D"},
        { text: "1W", resolution: "1W"},
    ],
});
```

I use UDF to transfer data from server to chart . the UDF return this response :

```
{"s":"ok","t":[1612432588,1612446988],"c":[10000,9999],"o":[21000,9999],"h":[21000,9999],"l":[10000,9999],"v":[76300,19998]}
```

after chart loaded I have a error in console :

```
PutToCacheNewBar: time violation, previous bar time: 2021-02-04T13:56:48.000Z should be less or equal to new time: 2021-02-04T09:56:58.000 
time order violation, prev: Thu, 04 Feb 2021 13:56:48 GMT, cur: Thu, 04 Feb 2021 09:56:58 GMT
```

and every time UDF loaded volume of candles changed !

Answer (score 1):

Found out when I remove the `has_empty_bars: true` from `resolveSymbol` config it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `putToCacheNewBar` error message occurs when a realtime update (from SubscribeBars) gives the chart a new bar which has a `time` value earlier than the current latest bar.
Realtime updates should only update the latest bar (the time is the same), or provide a newer bar (time is later). And it should only provide data for a single bar.

https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/JS-Api#subscribebarssymbolinfo-resolution-onrealtimecallback-subscriberuid-onresetcacheneededcallback

Answer (score 0):

bars array should be sorted in ascending based on 'time' value.